# Problems with maven release on git

Tags: git, maven-release-plugin, maven-scm

I've got a very strange problem: Every time I want to release my open source project (hosted on github) maven is uploading a snapshot to my repository instead of the expected release.

I've found out, the problem is that the pom of the release tag (git) contains a snapshot version. It seems means release:prepare doesn't set the correct release version for the release tag.

I'm using maven 3.2.3 and git 2.0.1.

The pom.xml [here](https://github.com/th-schwarz/C5Connector.Java/blob/master/pom.xml).

Every hint is welcome.

Comment: The link gives a 404. Please include your pom.xml here.

Comment: @Markus: I've fixed the link.

Comment: My first guess would be https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-812, but you seem to be using the latest version where this issue is already fixed. I'm not sure if git-2.0.1 is already supported, that might be the issue. Releassing with an additional `-X` will show the git commands done, which should give you a hint of what's going wrong.

Comment: @ThiloSchwarz: Linking code is frowned upon. If your repo is deleted, there question becomes meaningless and the answer may become useless for others.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg: Didn't found any possibility to attach the file. Pasting to the editor the file lost its formatting and isn't readable.

Comment: Indent by four spaces, which denotes code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is because of https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-812.

It should be fixed in 2.5. However see the [comment](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRELEASE-812?focusedCommentId=351340&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-351340)

I used this plugin configuration

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-gitexe</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.scm</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scm-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</plugin>
```

and it works for me.

PS: Use `mvn release:prepare -DpushChanges=false` when you test the plugin. The changes are only local than and you can reset them.

Comment: Interesting: maven-release-plugin 2.5.1 already uses maven-scm-1.9.2 (http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/dependencies.html). In the original pom.xml the m-release-p was already locked to this version, which would suggest there's regression in 2.5.1. Can anyone confirm?

Comment: To confirm above solution. Moving to a version of the plugin >= 2.5 resolved this for me.